# when map function is in the code it returns undefined and when console.log it returns the an empty object and an the data. i just want the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, fetch

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Slide = () => {

     let [nasaDa, setData] = useState({}); 

        function fetchData() { //fetch function to get the data from the server
            fetch('/done')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setData(data) // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error)) //console.log if there is an error with fetching data 
        }

     useEffect(() => {
         fetchData();   //calling the fetch function 
     }, [])

     return(
         <div className="slide" >
             {nasaDa.map((item, index) => { //mapping the data that should be returned from nasaDa
                 return [
                     <div key={index} className='mapDiv'>
                         <h>{item.name}</h>, 
                         <img src={item.img}/>, //mapping out the data from array 
                         <p>{item.des}</p>
                 ]
             })}
         </div>
     )
export default Slide;
```

when returned it gives `{} [{data}]`

what i need is just `[{data}]`

Comment: `fetch()` is asynchronous.

Comment: add if-else block. if(item.name) {return {...your code}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let [nasaDa, setData] = useState(null); 

    function fetchData() { //fetch function to get the data from the server
        fetch('/done')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            setData(data) // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error)) //console.log if there is an error with fetching data 
    }

 useEffect(() => {
     fetchData();   //calling the fetch function 
 }, [])

 return(
     <div className="slide" >
         {nasaDa && nasaDa.map((item, index) => { //mapping the data that should be returned from nasaDa
             return <div key={index} className='mapDiv'>
                     <h>{item.name}</h>, 
                     <img src={item.img}/>, //mapping out the data from array 
                     <p>{item.des}</p>
            </div>
         })}
     </div>
 )
```

Fetch data is async and you need a mechanism to know if your data is loaded or not. I set the initial state to null and added a check before map so you don't get anything rendered. You could choose to render a spinner or something else on that state.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please update the answer to explain what you changed and why.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do the rendering in the callback function?

Comment: no. You set the state, wich triggers react to call rerender that updates your HTML. when fetchData finishes (since it is async) react has already finished with the first render, so setState is a way for you to tell react that something changed and it should reflect those changes in HTML

Comment: glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to help anyone other with same problems

Comment: Can't you set the state in the callback, instead of using a timer?